XAF Winforms Memory Leak
I am checking the XAF Winform (XPO) and found that it holds the objects in memory even if the View (listview, detailview) is closed.
The result is, if we open the screen many time then the memory is going up. And finally we have out of memory.
Checking using ".NET Memory Profiler" and I see "Live Instances" increased each time we open a Listview.
Documents
Is it a memory leak in Winfom XAF (XPO) or it is designed in that way?
The version i am using is 20.2. I don't add any custom codes or controller.t
Thank you
Checking using ".NET Memory Profiler" and I see "Live Instances" increased each time we open a Listview.
